# How to fix router.delete() which is not working - Express.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am trying to run a delete request but it is not working, I have used the exact same logic on another project exactly like it and it works there.

Here is the route file which includes the delete request as well as the post request that does indeed work

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/users");
const cardSchema = require("../models/card");

//add card request
router.post("/:id/addcard", getUser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.body != null) {
      const newCard = new cardSchema({
        name: req.body.name,
        cardNumber: req.body.cardNumber,
        ccv: req.body.ccv,
        expiration: req.body.expiration,
      });
      res.user.cardInfo.push(newCard);
    }
    const updatedCardInfo = await res.user.save();
    return res.status(200).json(updatedCardInfo);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

//delete card request
router.delete("/:id/deletecard", getUser, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body !== null) {
    res.user.cardInfo.remove(req.body);
  }

  try {
    const updatedUser = await res.user.save();
    res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

//get user middleware
async function getUser(req, res, next) {
  let user;
  try {
    user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

    if (user == null) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Cannot find user" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }

  res.user = user;
  next();
}

module.exports = router;
```

I have triple checked that I am using the correct URL and passing in the correct information in the req.body. I recieved the users information after calling the delete request but just does not remove the card information. I have also checked in my database that it is 'cardInfo' so there is no spelling mistake there either.

Comment: Are you testing with a `curl` or from an ajax request in the browser?  And if it's the latter, are you using an ajax library like `axios`?  or are you using `fetch`?

Comment: i am using postman to make my request

Comment: Can you tell that you're getting the body payload?  I ask because with `axios` there is a little syntax trick to make sure, for `DELETE` calls, the payload gets put in the right place.  So i wonder - since you have the `if (!req.body)` if that is what's missing.  Probably a silly question.  I guess I just saw your comment "and passing the correct info in the req.body" - so you checked that.

Comment: `DELETE` requests, like `GET` should not have a request body